# Definiton of limit superior

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I understand generally what limit superior is. But I don't understand one thing in definition of limit superior in book (G. Bartle R. Sherbert "Introduction to real analysis"), I will be grateful if somebody explain me this one.

Let $X=(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers.

Definiton: The limit superior of $(x_n)$ is the infimum of the set $V$ of $v \in \mathbb R$ such that $v<x_n$ for at most finite number of $n \in \mathbb N$.

How can the set $V$ look like? I think that $V$ is unbounded below, therefore it can not has an infimum. For example let $(x_n)=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$, so $(x_n)$ is bounded, the set $V$ is $V=\{v<x_n\}$ for at most finite number of $n \in \mathbb N$, then $V=$ an interval $(-\infty,7]$ so it's true, because we have $n=1$.( for one member of our sequence we have  $v<x_n$ for at most finite number $n\in \mathbb N$ so for 1 number.) I intuitively understand that I'm doing something wrong, but what? Can u explain me, what is the set $V$?

Thank you for help!

Comment: When people say sequence, we almost always mean $(x_n)$ indexed for $n\in\Bbb N$, so your finite set of $(x_n)=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$, which stops at $n=8$, is unsuitable

Comment: @FShrike ok, thank you. But how can $V$ look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to consider $V$ for $x_n$ a finite sequence. But, let's consider $(x_n)=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,\cdots$ which is now a proper $\Bbb N$-indexed sequence.

For this "proper" sequence I provide, $V=[8,\infty)$. The infimum of $V$ is absolutely equal to $8$, as you would expect. Why can't $V$ contain $v\lt 8$? For such $v$, $v\lt x_n=8$ for all $n\ge 8$, which is an infinite set (this is why the sequence must be infinite for the definition to work).

This contrasts your finite example, since in that case $V=\Bbb R$ as trivially everything holds for "all most finitely many" of the $x_n$ as $x_n$ was finite in your example.

Let's make a more complicated example. Let $x_n=\sin(n)$. By the irrationality of $\pi$ it is impossible for $x_n$ to equal $-1,0$ or $1$, ever, but it can be shown (e.g. by equidistribution) that $x_n$ comes arbitrarily close to $1$, so $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$ (note that the limit does not exist, as $\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n=-1$). How do we reason about this in terms of $V$? Well, $[1,\infty)\subseteq V$ for sure, since $v\lt x_n$ is never true. Can $v\lt 1$ exist in $V$? Well because I am claiming $\sin(n)$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$, if we fix a $v_0\lt 1$ there will be $n_1$ such that $\sin(n_1)\gt v_0$. There will also be $n_2\gt n_1,\,n_3\gt n_2,\,\cdots$ by periodicity of $\sin$. It won't be in an unbroken block of $n_1,n_1+1,n_1+2,\cdots$, like it was for the simpler $8,8,8,8,\cdots$ example, but such a sequence $n_1,n_2,\cdots$ will exist, without a doubt. Therefore, $V\cap(-\infty,1)=\emptyset$. We conclude that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\inf[1,\infty)=1$.

One more example. Let $x_n=e^{-n}\sin(n)$. So far, our examples of $V$ have all been closed intervals. This is not true here. Let $v\le 0$. $v\lt x_n$ for infinitely many $n$, fairly clearly, so such $v\notin V$. What about $v\gt0$? Since $|\sin(n)|\lt 1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}=0$, if I hold a $v_0\gt0$ fixed, there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $n\gt N$, $e^{-n}\sin(n)=x_n\lt v_0$. Specifically, $N=\ln(1/v_0)$. Anyway, this shows that for some "*tail*" of the sequence $\{x_{N+1},x_{N+2},\cdots\}$, $x_n\lt v_0$ always. In particular, $v_0\lt x_n$ for only finitely many $n$. This finite number may be huge, but it is still finite. Then $V=(0,\infty)$ which is an example of when $V$ is an open interval. The infimum of $V=0\notin V$, but nonetheless $0=\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sin(n)$, which is intuitive and correct. In fact, $0=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}\sin(n)$ as well.

There is another definition you will see:

> $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\inf_{n\in\Bbb N}\underset{v\in V}{\underbrace{\sup_{m\ge n}x_n}}$$

This captures the same idea, maybe slightly more understandably. $\sup_{m\ge n}x_m$ is precisely any $v$ such that $v\lt x_m$ for at most finitely many $m$ (indeed, for at most $n$ such $m$ by construction). We then take the infimum of this set to get the "tightest" bound, for a limit superior. Think about my last example, with a *tail* of a sequence. This is what $\sup_{m\ge n}x_m$ captures.

Comment: thank you for a great answer. But if you take $V=[8, \infty)$, then if I take arbitrary $v \in V$ then we have $x_n \ \leq \ v \forall\ n \in \mathbb N$, but by definition it has to be $v<x_n$. Is it your mistake or my misunderstanding?

Comment: "$v\lt x_n$ for at most finitely many $n$" translates to "$8\lt x_n$ for at most finitely many $n$". As $8\lt x_n$ is never true, this holds. @mathguruu Think that $x_n\le v\forall n\in\Bbb N$ means $v$ is a valid upper bound, a valid candidate for a supremum.

Comment: super. thank you, now I understood it.)

Comment: @mathguruu You're welcome. As a passing note, $\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n$ is often defined as $\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\inf_{m\ge n}x_m$ in a manner similar to the one I describe above for limsup. This is like a supremum of $G$ where $G$ contains all $g$ such that $g\gt x_n$ holds for at most finitely many $n$.

Comment: Oh and - I should have said $V=\Bbb R$ for your finite example, not $V=(-\infty,8]$. That really was my mistake! Notice that $V=\Bbb R$ is basically useless... this is why infinitude of the sequence matters for this definition (although the limit superior/inferior can be infinite)

Comment: thank you so much!) Have a nice day)